# Sum of column equals, A - B

Tags: php, mysql

This may be a fairly straight forward one. I'm playing around with a little app I'm trying to create. I've got a form where users submit their "buy_price" and "sell_price". I am then trying to work out if they have made a loss or a profit. Would it be better to have a column within the database that works out the "margin" i.e "margin coulmn = sell_price-buy_price" (and how would I do this). Or would it be better to do this within php.

Thank you in advance.

Dan

Edit: I use a database because I store the data and then they can view their purchase history. I then want to make a section such as "best trades" for ones with highest margin etc.

Comment: Why would you need to involve a database? There is obviously much information about this simple requirement you have failed to mention

Comment: I personally feel like such a simple calculation should be done by the application rather than the database. I save the database calculations for complex stored procedures that need information from other tables. But I am no expert (hence why this is not an answer).

Comment: Your question is, "will it be better" which ends up being an opinion.  This is not a good fit for SO / SE.  Questions with one single provable answer are the intent of the site. [FAQ]

Comment: The fact you already have conflicting answers shows that the answer to this question is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I absolutely would not store calculated values in the database that are this simple - maintenance would likely outweigh any marginal gains in efficiency.

Even without storing the value, you still have an option on whether to calculate the value upon retrieval (with `MySQL`) or with PHP when rendering.

```
SELECT buy_price, sell_price, (buy_price - sell_price) AS margin FROM x
```

`SQL` aside, I'd still go with calculating it upon render with `PHP`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Say I chose to calculate the margin with PHP, would it then be difficult to order by "best margin"?

Comment: If you're needing to sort a large amount of data, I would actually go with MySQL - and would likely create a new view to do the sorting... but you don't have to. In the example I gave, you could just add an `ORDER BY margin DESC|ASC` to accomplish the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do this calculation in the database and to embed the value in a view:

```
create view vw_table as
    select t.*, (buy_price - sell_price) AS margin
    from table t;
```

Why is using a view (or in other databases a computed column) better?

First, is ensures that the same definition and name is going to be used wherever need "margin".  Second, using the view helps to separate the application layer from the database layer.  So, you can change the name of a table or column *without* having to rewrite the application -- you just change the view.  Third, in many environments, the margin can be calculated in parallel on a large volume of data, rather than having to be calculated sequentially in the application.  (On the other hand, a slightly larger amount of data is being returned to the client.)

Comment: +1, especially for explaining why it is better.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "better" very much depends on your application. It often refers to which operation is faster, which would require you to run a benchmark (but I'm guessing it's PHP). However, speed is probably not an issue for you, so "better" becomes simply whichever is easier for you to do. This is almost definitely PHP.